# How do I transfer .apk files to device using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

Gotta problem.  My employer won't allow anybody access to run / line command tools on our computers.  No way to run ADB (Android Debug Bridge) without that control.  I'm using windows, no way to access the registry, no way to manually add cmd.exe, i've tried..)  Screwing the staff is a sure way to reduce IT costs though, sigh.

I notice that sometimes when testing thru Eclipse with a real device plugged in via USB, that the application shows up on my android device..   and other times not.

Is there any way to use the Eclipse tools with Android plug in to 'install' the applications that I'm writing onto my real, physical device?  They test fine as long as I'm USB plugged in. but don't remain after I disconnect.

I know, getting a new employer is probably the best answer here, but that's not in the cards right now.  Good suggestion though  : )

Anyone know of a work around for program installation to hardware?

Many thanks in advance,
zip

Comment: Update, 22 Sept 2010. I haven't used the load to SD card method, though I suspect that will work well. I have written numerous programs in the past few weeks. Some of them remain on my deployment test hardware, some don't.

Comment: Question for you guys. When you plug the phone to the USB you get four connection type choices 1) Charge phone over USB only 2) HTC Sync 3) Disk Drive 4) USB Tethering. I've noticed that when I select choice #1, power charge only, the Eclipse / ADB functions well, but.... I'm suspecting there is a tie with the manner of my connection and ability to get to program again after disconnect. Saves are still irregular.

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't need to do anything special.  When you run an app from Eclipse, whether you are running it on the emulator or a device, it just uses adb to install it.  If you disconnect from your computer at that point, it will remain.  It is installed.  There isn't a special "app running but not installed" state.

I'd be really curious to know in what situations you are finding your up uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, if you're seeing your USB device (or emulator) in Eclipse, then `adb` is already running. Even if you can't start it manually from the command line, Eclipse will start it automatically on demand if you try to deploy an APK.

Answer (score 2):

I install the apk I am working on to a real device using [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com). Copy .apk from /bin directory right into your dropbox and then use the dropbox app to d/l and install it on the phone.

Comment: Interesting idea for remote devices!

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your device's filesystem when plugged in via USB.  From here, copy the .apk from your development computer to a location on the sdcard.  Finally, get a free app like Astro File Manager or AndroZip to find the .apk on your device's filesystem.  Once you select the .apk, you should be prompted with how you want to open it.  If you open it with the app manager, you can install/uninstall it on the device.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the .apk from `/bin/res` to, say, the desktop (or a desired folder in DropBox if you have it)
2. Hook your phone up via USB and make it a storage device (ie: flash drive).
3. Drag the file in, double click on it and choose install

I have 3 android phones, one Android 2.1 and two with ICS, and they aren't all recognized the standard way.

Comment: I've edited your post, but please be aware for future reference that proper grammar, capitalization, and spelling, are highly requested. Intentionally using poor grammar is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to load the apk onto an SD card, through a PC's USB port, then plug in that SD card into the handset (most android phones have micro SD card support). Now launch the apk and install it from there.

Answer (score 0):

When your device is connected to your PC via the USB debug cable, go to Eclipse. While your application project is open, select Run from upper menu. Then select your device from the window and run. This should be enough to load your application to your device. Now, even when you disconnect the USB cable, the application should be there.