# How to install .apk files through eclipse when i run the project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, robotium

I am new to robotium testing.

I wanted to open the emaulator and install the .apk files while I run the project.

Can anyone please let me know, how to implement this in Eclipse?

Comment: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697653/how-do-i-transfer-apk-files-to-device-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project in eclipse and select Run As > Android Application.

If you have an emulator set up already, then it will ask you to select one of your AVD. Otherwise, you will have to create your own Android Virtual Device

Answer (score 0):

Open your android folder(D:\Apps\java\embd\mobiles\android\4.1\platform-tools) and copy **.apk** file to the folder

open the avd manager and create avd

open command prompt and navigate to the folder and type as **adb install filename.apk** this will install the .apk files on to the emulator

if u want to unistall any .apk file just type as **adb uninstall filename.apk**